# showing that $\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot\frac{c+d}{2} =\big( \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\big)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I could expand the right side of the equation below to show that the sides are equal but I was wondering if there was some equality that would have allowed me to see that the left side equals the right?  and $a,b,c,d >0$

$$ = \frac{a+b}2 \cdot \frac{c+d}2 \cdot \frac{a+b+c+d}4 = \Big( \frac{a+b+c+d}4 \Big)^3 $$

Here's the **entire proof**.  The problem is from Arthur Engel's problem solving strategies in the section on inequalities.  The question was to prove the inequality below

$3$. We have

$$ \frac{abc + abd + acd + bcd}4 = \frac12 \Big( ab \frac{c+d}2 + cd \frac{a+b}2 \Big) $$
$$ \le \frac12 \Big( \Big( \frac{a+b}2 \Big)^2 \frac{c+d}2 + \Big( \frac{c+d}2 \Big)^2 \frac{a+b}2 \Big) $$
$$ = \frac{a+b}2 \cdot \frac{c+d}2 \cdot \frac{a+b+c+d}4 \le \Big( \frac{a+b+c+d}4 \Big)^3. $$

Hence,

$$ \sqrt[3]{ \frac{abc + abd + acd + bcd}4 } \le \frac{a+b+c+d}4 \le \sqrt{ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}4}. $$

Comment: It cannot be true, you will never have a term in $a^3$ for the LHS for example.

Comment: This is clearly false.  The left hand vanishes if $a=-b$ but the right hand does not.

Comment: @mfl oh, it's meant to be an identity of polynomials.  The restriction can't save it.

Comment: You really want to show that $\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot\frac{c+d}{2} \le \big( \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\big)^2$ because the right minus left is a square. This is AM-GM inequality.

Comment: I think it could be a typo.  See @Somos's comment above.

Comment: @Somos  How did you get the right minus left to be a square?  I get $0\leq \big(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\big)^2-\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot\frac{c+d}{2}$ but am not sure how to combine them to get a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

- $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$
- $y= \frac{c+d}{2}$

then

$$\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot\frac{c+d}{2} =\big( \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\big)^2\iff xy=\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2$$

which is false in general indeed by AM-GM

$$\frac{x+y}{2}\ge \sqrt{xy} \iff xy\le \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2$$

and equality holds if and only if $x=y$.